# UWP Groove Music Title Bar

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app

How can I make a `TitleBar` like Groove Music? It has an auto back button with the app name. Additionally, it's `NavigationViewPane` is extended to the `TitleBar`.

So I first added:
`Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;`

and then make the back button of `NavigationView` visible. However, there is a [known issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50170092/uwp-navigationview-control-titlebar) with that. Basically, part of that back button is covered by something which makes it only clickable somewhere. Although a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47078264/extend-buttons-to-title-bar-in-uwp) is provided here, it doesn't seem to have a good compatibility with the `AppViewBackButton` (for example I only want the `AppViewBackButton` to be blue) and I couldn't make it work.

Then I tried using `SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButton` but that button doesn't seem to be same as the Groove Music, because that one aligns well with the buttons in the `NavigationView`. I could redesign the `NavigationViewStyle` to make them fit but that requires a lot of work (how do I get the size of AppBackButton or how to customize it?). And the OpenPane of the `NavigationView` has a shadow but I didn't find it in the original style.

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Hi Seaky, could share screenshot to explain *part of that back button is covered by something which makes it only clickable somewhere*.?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Ah sorry since I am not working on that solution I cannot easily post a screenshot. But what I mean is that if I have a custom button in the TitleBar, the area in the TitleBar cannot be clicked while the area below can.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Hello Nico, I have customized the TitleBar a little in the [NowPlayingFullPage](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/NowPlayingFullPage.xaml). Can you see why the BackButton of that is not clickable?

Comment: ok, I will check.

Comment: The problem is the button is click able control if you call `SetTitleBar` method, the button will disable.  Please add the  `CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;` and remove  `Window.Current.SetTitleBar(EmptyTitleBar);` in `NowPlayingFullPage` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> UWP Groove Music Title Bar

UWP Groove Music app's back button contains two types, one is NavigateView's `BackButton`, other is `AppViewBackButton`.

> for example I only want the `AppViewBackButton` to be blue

You could check the back button of Now Playing page, it is  `AppViewBackButton`that the background color follow the system setting. You could custom it by switching other color in the **Windows colors setting**.

[image]

**Update**

The problem is the button is click able control, if you call SetTitleBar method set the button as title bar, the button will disable. 
Please add the  following

```
CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;
```

And remove `Window.Current.SetTitleBar(EmptyTitleBar);` in NowPlayingFullPage method.

Comment: Thank you for your update. But if I remove that, then my title bar becomes not draggable.

Comment: Title bar should be fixed, I think the draggable is not good practice.

Comment: I mean the App Window is not draggable without SetTitleBar. With that, I can drag window around when I am pressing on the title bar. Sorry for the confusion. And I have set `IsHitTestVisible` to `true`.

Comment: Yep, I could reproduce your issue, it is really problem for this scenario, Please check Groove music now playing page , the back button is `AppViewBackButton`, I think the better way is that use AppViewBackButton just like Groove music.

Comment: For detail steps please refer this [blog](https://developerinsider.co/handle-back-button-pressed-in-uwp/).

Comment: But how do you make the `AppViewBackButton` have a different color from those 3 mandatory buttons? `AppViewBackButton` is not using `SystemHighlightColor` in my case.

Comment: I have found the [solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/title-bar). Almost simply copying the same code at the bottom will make it work.

Comment: Great, I'm viewing your new case !

Answer (score 0):

Just turn my comment under NicoZhu's post into an answer.

To create a title bar like Groove music, you need to customize it. And modify your code based on the code [here at the bottom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/title-bar).

Additionally, if you need to switch pages, you would better add this to the `Page_Loaded` event of pages that you will be switching so that your title bars are draggable:

```
Window.Current.SetTitleBar(AppTitleBar);
```